# I have a working Javascript code to add new html rows. How to delete one?

Tags: javascript, html

this following code works in adding new rows in HTMl:

```
function addRow() 
{
  var row = document.getElementById('row');
  var newRow = row.cloneNode(true);
  row.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, document.getElementById('submit_row'));
}
```

How can I add a new function to remove a row?  I tried searching but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a DOM element in Javascript you use the `removeChild` API.  This requires you to have the DOM element of both the container and the item you want to remove.

In this example if you wanted to remove the row with id `row` you would do the following

```
var row = document.getElementById('row');
row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild

Note: In this particular example it looks like you are adding multiple DOM nodes with the same `id` value.  Having duplicate `id` values is not allowed and will cause you many problems down the road.  Every `id` value needs to be unique.

One way to accomplish this would be to use a counter to append a unique suffix to every row you add.

```
var rowCounter = 0;
function addRow() 
{
  rowCounter++;
  var row = document.getElementById('row');
  var newRow = row.cloneNode(true);
  newRow.id = 'new_row_' + rowCounter;
  row.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, document.getElementById('submit_row'));
}
```

Comment: So this would work?    function DelRow()
{
 var row = document.getElementById('row');
 row.parent.removeChild(row);

}

Comment: @JohnJenkins yes, that would remove the element with the id `row`. However if you don't fix the issue where multiple elements have the id `row` it will likely give you ... interesting behavior

Comment: Sorry last question and I will leave you alone.  This is able to clone HTML rows perfectly, but the value from the dropdown field is not cloned.  Is it possible to retain the value of the field as well when cloned?

Comment: @JohnJenkins which field are you referring to?

Comment: I didnt list the HTML but it is within a basic <form> and I use a dropdown list and it can clone the text from the textfields but it cannot clone the value of the dropdown field.

Comment: @JohnJenkins could you post the HTML here or open a new question with the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the removeChild() function.

Comment: Always good to have a reference.  Here's the [MDN page for removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.removeChild).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your addRow() function.  You are cloning a node and then keeping the same ID of 'row'.

```
function addRow() 
{
  var row = document.getElementById('row');
  var newRow = row.cloneNode(true);

  // set newRow.id to something other than 'row'

  row.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, document.getElementById('submit_row'));
}
```

To remove a node, you can use removeChild(), to remove a child node from an element

For example, x.removeChild(y) would remove child y of node x.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the targeted row, you'd do this...

```
row.parentNode.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.deleteRow

*The docs are for `table`, but `tbody` elements have the same method.*

Answer (score 0):

If you return the rows from the function before appending them to the DOM, you can record them in an object or array.  Then you can easily remove them with removeChild (previously mentioned) without searching the document again.

Comment: Thanks guys I messed with it and got it to work by luck thank you again! :D